# My fortran program never stops executing

Tags: fortran, fortran90, do-while

I have a fortran program that never stops executing.

```
program russianmultiplication
implicit none
integer::x,y,ginx,giny,k=0

print*,'give a number'
read*,x
k=k+x
print*,'one more'
read*,y
if (y==1) then
    print*,x
end if                
do while(y/=1)
    ginx=x*2
    giny=y/2
    if (mod(giny,2)/=0) then
        k=k+ginx
    end if
end do
print*,'result',k
end program
```

Why does this program never end?

Comment: There are a few reasons that programs will never stop executing.  One: You have chosen a problem that will take years to finish.  Two: you have defined an infinite loop and the program is executing it unproductively forever.  Three: Your program is waiting for something to happen that will never happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never change `y` inside the loop, and have no `exit` statement, either. So either `y` is `1` on input, in which case the condition for the loop is never true and it never executes, or you never leave the loop since the condition is always true.

Comment: i changed y in the do while statement to giny and still, it never terminates.

Comment: program russianmultiplication
implicit none
integer::x,y,ginx,giny,k=0

print*,'give a number'
read*,x
k=k+x
print*,'one more'
read*,y
if (y==1) then
    print*,x
end if                
do while(y/=1)
    ginx=x*2
    giny=y/2
    if (mod(giny,2)/=0) then
        k=k+ginx
    end if
end do
print*,'result',k
end program

Comment: nvm solved it, your advice led me to the right path thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is perhaps a clearer version of the original program to do [Russian peasant multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication#Russian_peasant_multiplication):

```
PROGRAM Russian_peasant_multiplication
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER :: total, x, x_save, y, y_save

total = 0!running total
PRINT *, "x ="
READ *, x
x_save = x
total = total + x
PRINT *, "y ="
READ *, y
y_save = y
PRINT *, y, x
!do while(y/=1)
modulo: DO
  IF (y == 1) EXIT!replace DO WHILE for better control
  !ginx=x*2
  x = x * 2!okay to redefine since saved
  !giny=y/2
  y = y / 2!okay to redefine since saved
  !if (mod(giny,2)/=0) then
  IF (MOD(y, 2) /= 0) THEN!keep only odd numbers on the left
    PRINT *, y, x
    !k=k+ginx
    total = total + x
  END IF
END DO modulo
PRINT *, " "
PRINT *, x_save
PRINT *, "x"
PRINT *, y_save
PRINT *, "="
PRINT *, total
END PROGRAM Russian_peasant_multiplication
```

I've added useful comments and also pointed out where the logical was flawed.  Hope this helps.